# Firebase iOS crash report readability issues

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

While there are several similar questions, I feel this case is a bit different as my symbol files seem to appear on firebase.

Here's how my crash looks in xcode debugger (notice `fatal error` message in console and highlighted source code line caused crash):

[image: crash in xcode debugger]

Here's same exact crash in firebase:

[image: crash in firebase]

Notice there's no `fatal error` message and `exact source line` that caused the crash. So my question is: how can I see this information on firebase crash.

The text above `Upload symbol file to symbolicate` hints that this crash is not symbolicated; however I can see my symbols appear on `symbol files` tab; on the other hand symbol UUID on crash is never there on `symbol files` page.

[image: symbols on firebase crash]

**UPD Dec 7th, 2016**

Right now crash report appears to be symbolicated without any changes from my side

[image: Dec 7th google console crash report]

Comment: It's specifically asking about the symbols whose UUID starts with "D3E2".  Have you uploaded those?  I don't see it in the list you show.  Also bear in mind you'll have to generate another crash *after* the symbols are uploaded, in order to see the extra information.

Comment: @DougStevenson symbols are uploaded via `run script` at the build time, I'm also curious why UUID of crash is not there on `uploaded symbols` page

Comment: If you look carefully, that screen is showing 10 of 15.  Is it in the 5 we can't see here?  If you are certain that you have uploaded the correct symbols, and you can't figure out why they're not showing up, please contact support with all your project details and the exact steps you've taken.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, that UUID is not present on second page; Doug, when you look at this crash does it look symbolicated to you? I catch myself thinking how `btnCrashTap` would even appear there if the crash is not symbolicated

Comment: That UUID most likely refers to the `libswiftCore.dylib` framework. As this is provided by Apple you do not have and can't get the dSYM. The message is misleading.

Comment: @Kemi The symbols from various versions of iOS should be provided by Firebase Crash Reporting, and I believe those for 10.1 were made available last week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's an explanation](https://twittercommunity.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-exception-that-lead-to-the-crash/65997/4) from twitter staff member (Crashlytics) on why messages like this don't come through in crash reporting services:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work, even after logging in.

Comment: Well, it worked 4 years ago. Probably it's a good idea to screenshot the content for the sake of history.

Answer (score 1):

I checked in with the Firebase Crash Reporting team, and they said that there was a problem importing the iOS 10.1 symbols for the simulator.  Those symbols should be available now for crashes on the simulator.  If you generate a new crash, you should be able to see readable symbols now.

Comment: Doug, I've checked and that's true, now there's no error message on symbolication. What do you think on why that `fatal error` message is not appearing on firebase console crash reports - is that like guy from twitter staff says that it's difficult to capture that message from crash? Cheers.

Comment: Possibly - I do a lot of Android and almost no iOS.  I'll run it by the team again and see if someone knows.